# Какой командой скачать последний коммит из git?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

У меня есть последний коммит в Git в облаке, и есть поломанная версия проекта на самом компьютере, всё что нужно это скачать на компьютер последний сохранённый коммит. Как я понял, через GitHub Desktop это сделать нельзя. Какую команду нужно написать в GitBash, чтобы это сделать?

Comment: для того чтобы скачать придется сначала запушить изменения, как один из вариантов просто сделать  git clone ... в новой папке, либо git checkout <имя_файла> для отмены изменений в нем, какие файлы менялись git status покажет красным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно выполнить следующие команды для синхронизации локального проекта с удалённым репозиторием:

```
 git fetch --prune origin
 git reset --hard origin/master
 git clean -f -d
```

`git reset --hard origin/master` эта команда синхронизирует вашу локальную ветку с веткой на удаленном репозиторием, важно понимать что все локальные изменения с веткой не сохранятся.
Команда `git clean` используется для удаления ненужных файлов из вашего рабочего каталога.